# So my CPU is running at ~14 Ghz

Tags: windows-11, clockspeed

I've just noticed as I was checking the CPU temperatures on my MSI GF65 laptop using the latest Core Temp 1.17.1 and it's giving this obviously erroneous reading of the CPU clock speed.

I believe this only started happening when I upgraded to Windows 11, previously it used to show the clock per core but now it seems like it just displays the sum of all cores together.

Does anyone know if that is how it's meant to work now or is it some sort of a glitch?

[image]

Comment: What program are you using? Have you updated it to the latest version? Are you certain it supports your processor correctly?

Comment: Coretemp appears to be quite old: [April 12, 2021](https://www.techspot.com/downloads/6979-core-temp.html) so may well not be correctly reading newer processors. Try something like HWiNFO https://www.hwinfo.com/

Comment: It’s obviously incorrect. So it has to be a software bug

Comment: @Mokubai, yes, this is the latest version. newer than the CPU and according to the support page, it has to support all i7 CPUs. I try hwinfo, thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't upgrade to liquid-N2 coolant?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik, hahaha, I'm afraid it would hardly fit in the laptop case